# How to convert an Iterable of type X to type Y Re: Iterable<WordPair> to Iterable<String>

Tags: dart, iterable

In pubspec.yaml, I'm using english_words library to generate wordpairs:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
   sdk: flutter

 # Contains a few thousand of the most used English words
 # plus some utility functions.
 english_words: ^3.1.0
```

Now the WordPair Class is not a subtype of String and so I can't use the Iterable's lambdas or functions like cast or retype to 'cast' the 'WordPairs' to Strings.

So, I had to write the function called getWords().

See below the Dart file, Model.dart, that contains this implementation.

You'll see the old line commented out where it was returning in the getter the type Iterable.

Would there be a more efficient way to do this?

For example, I didn't want to involve a List Class in the conversion, but I can't find any other way to successfully do this.

Thanks.

----------------  Model.dart

```
 import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart' show WordPair, generateWordPairs;

 import 'dart:collection';

 /// Model Class
 ///
 class Model {

 String get randomWordPair => new WordPair.random().asPascalCase;

   //  Iterable<WordPair> get wordPairs =>  generateWordPairs().take(10);

 Iterable<String> get wordPairs => getWords();


  Iterable<String> getWords(){

     Iterable<WordPair> pairs = generateWordPairs().take(10);

     ListWords<String> words = new ListWords();

     for (var pair in pairs) {

       words.add(pair.asString);
     }

     return words;
   }
}


class ListWords<E> extends ListBase<E> {

  final List<E> l = [];

  set length(int newLength) { l.length = newLength; }

  int get length => l.length;

  E operator [](int index) => l[index];

  void operator []=(int index, E value) { l[index] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @sutch  Like many things on Stackoverflow, I've moved on to other problems....

Answer (score 2):

In Dart 2 you can use

```
iterable.cast<NewType>()
```

but it is prone to lead to inefficiency if the resulting list is accessed often, because it wraps the original iterable into a new one and has to forward every access.

Usually more efficient are

```
new List<NewType>.of(oldList)
```

or

```
new List.from<NewType.from(oldList)
```

I was not able to derive the difference between `.of()` and `from()` from the docs though (https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.50.0/dart-core/List/List.from.html, https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.50.0/dart-core/List/List.of.html)

Comment: this is the best answer, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, a loop that is collecting the result of an expression can generally be replaced with an appropriate `.map` method invocation on an `Iterable`.  See if that will help.